How does one handle mouseEntered: and mouseExited: events when nswindow style is fullSizeContentView?
I have a macOS app with a view that occupies the entire window, with NSWindowStyleMaskFullSizeContentView set within the window's styleMask. I want to show the titlebar and window buttons when the mouse enters the window, and hide them when the mouse exits the window.
I am using a tracking area whose rect is window.contentView.bounds, with the height of the titlebar subtracted from its height.
I have implemented the mouseEntered: and mouseExited: methods to handle the show/hide actions.
The problem I have is when I move the mouse to the window's titlebar, the app receives multiple mouseExited:/mouseEntered: events in rapid succession, causing a "fluttering" effect with the titlebar.
To reproduce this problem, I first created an Objective-C project in Xcode, and used IB to set the window property to 'Full Size Content View'. Then edited ViewController.m as shown:
    //
    //  ViewController.m
    //  Repro
    //
    
    #import "ViewController.h"
    
    @implementation ViewController
    {
        NSTrackingArea  *trackingArea;
    }
    
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    - (void)viewWillAppear
    {
        // background color
        self.view.wantsLayer = true;
        self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor systemBlueColor].CGColor;
    
        // tracking area
        [self setupTrackingArea:self.view.window.contentView.bounds];
        
        return;
    }
    - (void)setupTrackingArea:(CGRect)frame
    {
        if (trackingArea)
        {
            [self.view removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
        }
    
        NSTrackingAreaOptions   options = NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow | NSTrackingInVisibleRect | NSTrackingMouseMoved;
    
        // subtract the titlebar height from the content view height
        frame.size.height -= [self titlebarHeight:self.view.window];
    
        trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc]initWithRect:frame
                               options:options
                                 owner:self
                              userInfo:nil];
        [self.view addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
    }
    - (CGFloat)titlebarHeight:(NSWindow *)window
    {
        CGFloat windowHeight = window.contentView.frame.size.height;
        CGFloat contentHeight = window.contentLayoutRect.size.height;
        CGFloat titlebarHeight = windowHeight - contentHeight;
        return titlebarHeight;
    }
    
    - (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)event
    {
        [self showTitleBar];
        [self showWindowButtons:self.view.window];
    
        return;
    }
    - (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)event
    {
        [self hideTitleBar];
        [self hideWindowButtons:self.view.window];
        return;
    }
    
    - (void)showTitleBar
    {
        self.view.window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = false;
        self.view.window.title = @"Repro";
        return;
    }
    - (void)hideTitleBar
    {
        self.view.window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true;
        self.view.window.title = @"";
        return;
    }
    
    - (void)hideWindowButtons:(NSWindow *)window
    {
        [window standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton].hidden = true;
        [window standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton].hidden = true;
        [window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton].hidden = true;
        return;
    }
    - (void)showWindowButtons:(NSWindow *)window
    {
        [window standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton].hidden = false;
        [window standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton].hidden = false;
        [window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton].hidden = false;
        return;
    }

@end


Post a [mre] please.

Edited the question to include entire ViewController.m in repro.

Have you tried without the NSTrackingInVisibleRect option?

Yes. When NSTrackingInVisibileRect is not set, then the tracking area does not automatically resize when the window/view resizes.

See How to use NSTrackingArea.

Thanks to suggestions by Willeke (thanks so much for your help!), there is a solution. It involved subclassing NSView (I called it MyView), moving all of the tracking area handling into that view, and removing it from the ViewController. MyView.m is:
//
//  MyView.m
//  Repro
//

#import "MyView.h"

@implementation MyView
{
        NSTrackingArea  *trackingArea;
}

- (void)viewWillMoveToWindow:(NSWindow *)newWindow
{
        if (newWindow)
        {
                newWindow.styleMask |= NSWindowStyleMaskFullSizeContentView;

                [self setupTrackingArea:newWindow];
        }
        [super viewWillMoveToWindow:newWindow];
        return;
}
- (void)updateTrackingAreas
{
        [self setupTrackingArea:self.window];

        [super updateTrackingAreas];

        return;
}

- (void)setupTrackingArea:(NSWindow *)window
{
        if (trackingArea)
                [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];

        NSTrackingAreaOptions   options = NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways;
        trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc]initWithRect:self.bounds
                                                   options:options
                                                     owner:self
                                                  userInfo:nil];
        [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
        return;
}
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)event
{
        [self showTitleBar];
        [self showWindowButtons:self.window];

        return;
}
- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)event
{
        [self hideTitleBar];
        [self hideWindowButtons:self.window];
        return;
}

- (void)showTitleBar
{
        self.window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = false;
        self.window.title = [NSProcessInfo processInfo].processName;
        return;
}
- (void)hideTitleBar
{
        self.window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true;
        self.window.title = @"";
        return;
}

- (void)hideWindowButtons:(NSWindow *)window
{
        // hide the minimize and zoom buttons (yellow and green)
        [window standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton].hidden = true;
        [window standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton].hidden = true;
        [window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton].hidden = true;
        return;
}
- (void)showWindowButtons:(NSWindow *)window
{
        [window standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton].hidden = false;
        [window standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton].hidden = false;
        [window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton].hidden = false;
        return;
}
@end

